# How to create dedicated service catalog per OpenShift project?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin

Is it possible to create a dedicated service catalog for each project/namespaces in Openshift? I am hosting a multi-tenant OpensShift cluster. When each tenants login to OpenShift cluster, they should only be able see services which is relevant for them in the service catalog.

For eg: Tenant-A should only see MySQL and Apache services. Tenant-B should only see ElasticSearch and Ruby services. Is it possible to do this kind of isolation?

Comment: Don't load any templates or image stream into the ``openshift`` project. Load explicitly those you need into each project. You may have to modify some templates if they have been hardwired to refer to images from ``openshift`` project.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Any idea where can I get the templates for RedHat middleware solutions like JBoss EAP, EDB and EWS ?

Comment: If you are using OpenShift Origin, I don't believe middleware images and templates are available. They are only available if you are using OpenShift Container Platform from Red Hat through a subscription.

Comment: I am using RedHat Container Platform. Can I install all the necessary middleware templates and images using any specific commands from my Container platform.?

Comment: I don't know where the template and image stream definitions for them are. Better to ask through your Red Hat support channel.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamDumpleton for your suggestions

Comment: I have loaded few middleware templates and streams to a project (For eg: myproject) and pointed Template Service Broker api to refer the new project(myproject). Still I am not able to see my templates in service catalog (Openshift default dashboard). I am only seeing the default templates that was loaded automatically from "openshift" project initially. How can I permanently remove all the default templates from Openshift dashboard (Service catalog) and just show the middleware templates in my custom project.

Comment: When you add templates to a project, you need to go 'Add to Project', then 'Select from Project' if using OpenShift 3.7. They don't appear in 'Browse Catalog'.